# Are there reasons to use get/put methods instead of item access?

Tags: python, interface, mapping

I find that I have recently been implementing Mapping interfaces on classes which on the surface fit the model (they are essentially just key-value stores with no more meta-data), but underneath they are sometimes quite complex.

Here are a couple examples of increasing severity:

1. An object which wraps another mapping converting all objects to strings when set.
2. An object which uses a local database as a back-end to store the key-value pairs.
3. An object which makes HTTP requests to remote servers to get/set data.

Lets suppose all of these examples seamlessly implement the Mapping interface, and the only indication that there is something fishy going on is that item access potentially could take a few seconds, and an item may not be retrievable in the same form as stored (if at all). I'm perfectly content with something like the first example, pretty okay with the second, but I'm getting kinda uncomfortable with the last.

The question is, is there a line at which the API for these models should not use item access, even though the underlying structure may feel like it fits on the surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a strictly philosophical point of view, I don't think that there is a line you can cross with this.  If some tool provides the needed functionality, but its API is different, adapt away.  The only time you shouldn't do this is if the adapted to API simply is not expressive enough to manipulate the adapted component in a way that is needed.

I wouldn't hesitate to adapt a database into a dict, because that's a great way to manipulate collections, and it's already compatible with a heck of a lot of other code.  If I find that my particular application must make calls to the database connections `begin()`, `commit()`, and `rollback()` methods to work right, then a dict won't do, since dict's don't have transaction semantics.

Comment: But what if the transactions are optional? pybsddb does this: you can use dict-style access but you simply do not get access to transactions.

Comment: I mean I wouldn't use the dict adaptor in the case that my application actually wants to use those transaction semantics.  If you don't need them, or anything else typical of dicts, then go ahead and make it look like a dict!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are describing the standard [anydbm](http://docs.python.org/library/anydbm.html) module semantics. And just as anydbm can raise exception `anydbm.error`, so too could your subclass raise derivatives like `MyDbmTimeoutError` as needed. Whether you implement it as dictionary operations or function calls, the caller will still have to contend with exceptions anyway (e.g. `KeyError`, `NameError`).

I think that arbitrary "tied" hashes exist in Python 2 and 3.x is decent justification for saying it is a reasonable approach. Indeed, I've been looking for (and designing in my head) more complex bindings than simple key ⇒ value mappings without a heavy ORM SQL layer in between.

**added**: The more I think about it, the more Pythonic tied dictionaries seem to be. A key ⇒ value collection **is a** dictionary. Whether it lives in core or on disk or across the network is an implementation detail that is best abstracted away. The only substantive differences are increased latency and possible unavailability; however, on a virtual memory based OS, "core" can have higher latency than RAM and in a multiprocessing OS, "core" can become unavailable too. So these are differences in degree only, not kind.